# How to overload the operator "*" as KroneckerProduct

Tags: programming, expression-construction

Can I use the expression below

`a * b * c * d`

for short to instead

`KroneckerProduct[a,b,c,d]`

automatically when a,b,c,d are matrix.

The number of elements (a,b,c,d) is arbitrary, 
such as `a*b`, `a*b*c` and `a*b*c*d*e*f` all can work well.

---

It seems overriding the operator `*` in Mathematica is not a good method. And my special applicaon that importing expressions from external file in string format has some others ways.

Comment: Why does it have to be `*`? Why not use a different symbol instead? Overloading `Times[]` is usually not the way to go.

Comment: @J.M. Using "*" will make the expression look like a primitive math expression naturally and a loog expression can be easily understood.

Comment: $\phantom{ }$

Comment: @J.M. the operator "**" will also be good.

Comment: `⊗` would be the more traditional symbol for the Kronecker product, then.

Comment: Well, then... `Unprotect[NonCommutativeMultiply]; NonCommutativeMultiply = KroneckerProduct; Protect[NonCommutativeMultiply];` **Don't** try this at home, kids!

Comment: @J.M. great! great! great! That is what I need.

Comment: @J.M.  `a^dag` for `ConjugateTranspose[a]` is also possible?

Comment: You've seen [the docs](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/character/ConjugateTranspose.html), yes?

Comment: @J.M. To avoid to use `esc ... esc` . Some special  symbols will not be copied right.

Comment: How about telling us why you're unable or unwilling to use the traditional method of entering special characters?

Comment: @J.M. I want to generate some math expression in a .txt file and then load them into Mathematica for calculation. So I would like to use a way to wirte the expressions in plain string and as possible as native math expression while it can be directly understood by Mathematica.

Comment: Please take a look at [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/character/Star.html). This glyph is available for uses such as you propose.

Comment: @cmc please add to your question information from comment, that you want to import to *Mathematica* expressions from a text file, that has some specific format. This is very different problem than overriding built-in function for expressions that are already in *Mathematica*.

Answer (score 4):

It was clarified in comments that expressions are supposed to be read into *Mathematica* from a text file. To achieve what OP wants one can read the file as list of held expressions, perform appropriate replacements, then release hold.

If we have a `test.txt` file with following contents:

```plaintext
a * b * c * d
a^dag
```

We can read it in following way:

```
ReadList["test.txt", HoldComplete@Expression]
% /. {Times -> KroneckerProduct, x_^dag :> ConjugateTranspose[x]} // ReleaseHold
(* {HoldComplete[a b c d], HoldComplete[a^dag]} *)
(* {KroneckerProduct[a, b, c, d], ConjugateTranspose[a]} *)
```

If we have more control over format of this text file and can accept non-ASCII characters, then we could use [operators without built‐in meaning](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/OperatorsWithoutBuiltInMeanings.html), as already [suggested in comments](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/116211/how-to-overload-the-operator-as-kroneckerproduct/116259#comment315456_116211). With `unicode.txt` file:

```plaintext
a ⊗ b ⊗ c ⊗ d
a^†
```

we could do this:

```
ReadList["unicode.txt", HoldComplete@Expression]
% /. {
    CircleTimes -> KroneckerProduct,
    x_^\[Dagger] :> ConjugateTranspose[x]
} // ReleaseHold
(* {a ⊗ b ⊗ c ⊗ d, a^†} *)
(* {KroneckerProduct[a, b, c, d], ConjugateTranspose[a]} *)
```

Comment: That doc page link is so useful. Thank you jkuczm!